# How can I automate downloading files from a website using different inputs using Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, automation, download, request

I need to download a number of data from the website https://www.renewables.ninja/ and I want to automate the process using Python if possible.

I want to select cities (say Berlin, New York, Seoul) as well as parameters for solar PV and wind based on the inputs from a Python file, and run it (which takes approximately 5 seconds in the website) and download the csv files.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wElg1.png)

Is it possible to automate this process using Python since I need to download a large number of files for different data points?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwX1P.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's definitely possible to automate this process.
Consider looking at this url: https://www.renewables.ninja/api/data/pv?local_time=true&format=csv&header=true&lat=52.5170365&lon=13.3888599&date_from=2019-01-01&date_to=2019-12-31&dataset=merra2&capacity=1&system_loss=0.1&tracking=0&tilt=35&azim=180&raw=false

It's a request to API for SolarPV data.You can change query parameters here and get data for cities that you want.Just change lat and lon parameters.

To get these parameters for city you can use this API: https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&limit=1&q=berlin. Change q parameter here for city that you want.

Code example:

```
import json
import requests 

COORD_API = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search"
CITY = "berlin"  # It's just an example.

payload = {'format': 'json', 'limit': 1, 'q':CITY}
r = requests.get(COORD_API, params=payload)
lat_long_data = json.loads(r.text)

lat = lat_long_data[0]['lat'] 
lon = lat_long_data[0]['lon']

# With this values we can get Solar data
MAIN_API = "https://www.renewables.ninja/api/data/pv?local_time=true&format=csv&header=true&date_from=2019-01-01&date_to=2019-12-31&dataset=merra2&capacity=1&system_loss=0.1&tracking=0&tilt=35&azim=180&raw=false"

payload = {'lat': lat, 'lon': lon}
resp = requests.get(MAIN_API, params=payload)

***

Do something with this data.
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response! Could you possibly let me know how the code should look like in Python as I am new to this topic?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the files and save them using the requests module as follows:

```py
import requests

with open('saved_data_file.csv','w') as f:
    csv_data = requests.get('https://www.renewables.ninja/api/data/weather',
                             params={"format":"csv"}).content
    f.write(csv_data)
```

If you want to see what parameters are used when you request certain data from the website open inspect element (F12) and go to the network tab. Request data using their form and have a look at the new request that pops up. The URL will look something like this:

```
https://www.renewables.ninja/api/data/weather?local_time=true&format=csv&header=true&lat=70.90491170356151&lon=24.589843749945597&date_from=2019-01-01&date_to=2019-12-31&dataset=merra2&var_t2m=true&var_prectotland=false&var_precsnoland=false&var_snomas=false&var_rhoa=false&var_swgdn=false&var_swtdn=false&var_cldtot=false
```

Then pickout the parameters you want and put them in a dictionary that you feed into `requests.get` e.g. `params={"format":"csv","local_time":"true","header":"true" etc.}`